# C# Is there a method to Synchronize/Lock all methods on an object automatically?

Tags: c#, multithreading, methods, synchronization, thread-safety

I am currently using `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]` on all my class's methods to have it be thread safe.

Is there a method that can apply that to all the methods of a class without having to explicitly prepend it to every function declaration?

Like a shorthand version of it that I can put atop the class itself?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to use `MethodImpl` this way. Your code will has high potential for deadlocks and your performance will reduce considerably

Comment: Don't know about a method, but do know about the whole concept that aims what you are asking for — actor model! Take a look at `Orleans` project. By default, all methods of actors are thread safe.